# Refactor settings module to settings object (python)

Tags: python, refactoring

I have a small python application (about 6000 loc), where I keep my settings in a seperate
module, settings.py. As the application grew, I started to add tests. Now after having
more and more tests, and trying to test with different settings, I find that the module
approach was not such a great idea, as its not very flexible - I always have to reason
about where and when settings.py gets imported, so that I do my modifications at the
right place etc.

Now I have a new approach, which still uses the settings.py, but it will get imported only
once, and turned into an config object that I can pass around and modify locally without affecting anything else. I could now have different versions
of settings.py, the config object constructor takes a filename as an optional argument.
So I think I am better prepared for my testing.

Now comes the refactoring, and bevor I dive into it, I would like to get a second (or third ;)) opinion on
how to tackle the refactoring. Here is my idea:

1. All functions and methods that use the settings module get a keyword argument for a
   settings module (settings=None).
2. Decorate all these functions with a decorator that injects the settings object if its
   not given by the original caller. Also, warn about the injection, so that I am aware
   of where I need to modify the call.

At this point, I should still have working code, and can start hunting for the callers.
Also, step 1 and 2 could be done by a script, to reduce the tedium. Once I have removed all warnings by correcting the calls, I can remove the decorator.

In this way, in my thinking, I never have a state were I need to change a lot of things at once to have working code, thus having a smooth journey.

Does that sound like a reasonable approach? Or am i overthinking this? Or miss any
important points?

Comment: why not use: https://pythonhosted.org/ConfigObject/

Comment: That looks nice - however it does not do the refactoring itself ;) So I still need to refactor somehow. Since no one has objected to my above plan I assume that its at least not completely stupid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I wouldn't do either option and just have each module/file to instantiate your `Config` object at import time.

So in most of your code your going to be replacing:

```
Import config
```

With:

```
from configuration import Config
config = Config()
```

You can then use the object in exactly the same way you did the module.

This will get you a separate `Config` object without having to modify every function in your app, frees you from global config and allows  you to easily patch the config of module your testing without it affecting the config of your imports.

That's going to be easy to do and might by as deep as you need to go.

Comment: "That's going to be easy to do and might by as deep as you need to go." Exactly. I had the feeling I was making things more complicated then nessessary, but did not see the easy solution. Cheers!

Comment: Isn't this solution prone to race conditions?